# save node after paypal payment success

Tags: nodes, commerce, ubercart, payment-gateways

In my projects, Whenever Authenticated user create new content(page) they should redirect to paypal for done payment when they click save. Once Payment Success Node should be save otherwise its should not save.

Please help me for Fix this concept.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Get the response from Pay-pal if the response code is 200 save the node otherwise don't save it.

**for example :**

```
if ($responseCode == 200){
  //node_save($node);
}
else {
  print "payment failed";
}
```

https://www.drupal.org/node/1207878
check this for more info only for condition to check the payment status.

Comment: In my project User can add Advertisement. So i have created one content type called Advertisement. Whenever Authenticated user want to add new Advertisement they can create but when they click save button its should goto paypal. once payment done advertisement can publish otherwise that advertisement should not.

So i have no idea for implement this. can anyone help me??